# Is it possible to create Compound-Primary-key in a model in lift's mapper

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

Is it possible to create compound-Primary-key in Models in lift ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible in lift according to [this mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/f94722c78932ad63?pli=1),
where **David Pollak** say's

> It's pretty non-trivial.  I made some huge mistakes with Mapper and
>   making it super-not-easy to do compound PKs was one of a long list of
>   blunders. Sorry... but if I had a time machine, I'd got back 3 1/2
>   years and leave a note for myself that includes "Support compound
>   primary keys in Mapper.